# Javascript + Differentiate user clicks and clicks sent from function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Accordion function like this:

```
$("#notaccordion").addClass("ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset")
   .find("h3")
   .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom")
    .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>')
    .click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active").toggleClass("ui-state-active")
          .toggleClass("ui-state-default").toggleClass("ui-corner-bottom")
          .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
       if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
          ;
          $(this).addClass('active'); $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
       }
       else {
          $(this).removeClass('active'); $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
       }

       //.end().next().slideUp('normal');
       return false;
    })
    .next().addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom").hide();
```

and a click all panels function to expand all panels at once:

```
function clickAllPanels() {
   var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
   var i = elm.length; while (i--) {
      clickItem(elm[i]);
    }
}

function clickItem(divObj) {
   if (divObj.click) {
      divObj.click();
   } else if (document.createEvent) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      var allowDefault = divObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
   }
}
```

How can I let the accordion `.click(function ()` function know that it's `clickAllPanels` that is sending the 'clicks' instead of a user's physical click. I need to do this because I want to change the slide up and down logic if it's from `clickAllPanels`.

Comment: Is it not possible to open all panels without a emulating a click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often a good idea to have separate functions for the event handler and for the actual work you are doing:

```
function do_stuff(suitable_arguments, a_flag){
    //...
}

$(/*...*/).click(function(){
   do_stuff( /*...*/, true);
}

in_my_other_code(){
   do_stuff( /*...*/, false);
}
```

By detaching your logic from the event handling you have much more flexibility in choosing when and how to invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd do it is to use two different event names, one being "click" and the other being something like "forced-click":

```
$( ... whatever ... ).bind("click forced-click", function(ev) {
  if (ev.type === "forced-click") {
    // called by programmatic trigger
  }
  // ...
});
```

When you trigger the event:

```
$( ... whatever ... ).trigger("forced-click");
```

Another way to do it I guess would be to check the event object to see if there's an "originalEvent" property. If not, then you know it was triggered programmatically. Personally I don't like to rely on that because it's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jquery in your 'clickItem()' function:

```
function clickItem(divObj) {
    $(divObj).trigger('click', { manual: true });
}
```

The event parameter in you click handler will have a property "isTrigger", which won't exist when items are clicked with the mouse:

```
$("#notaccordion")
    ...
    .click(function(e) {

        if (e['isTrigger']) {
            // do this
        } else {
            // do that
        }

    });
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/va9VB/)